# Getting updates from Google App engine to Android app

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I created and stored an Entity from my Android app to Google App Engine and i am now able to view the Entity and it's properties in the `Datastore viewer` in Google Api Console.Now, i manually edited a value in the datastore and i want that change to reflect in my Android app.Is there a way to `"ping"` GAE once in a while from my Android app to see if there are changes and update the app if that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both Push and Pull Mechanisms to get updates in your Android application depending on your requirement.

- You could look at Push Notifications from the App Engine application to inform your application of changes. You ideally do not want to push a lot of information via Push Notification. Just an indication or a little bit of microdata that things have changed. This notification will be received in your Android application and you can then either update the Android app or invoke a App Engine Server side API to get more information.
- You could write a Service in your Android application that can poll an App Engine Server API regularly for any updates. If the data has changed on your Server side, then the API will give these changes back to the Android Service that can then set the state.

Comment: Am reading on this and it seems i need to use a third party server provider? I want to do this using only Google Cloud Messaging.